# How to Sort Results of Tab in Matrix

Tags: matrix, stata

Say I have the data created by the following:

```
clear all
set obs 150
set seed 1234
foreach i in 1 2 {
    gen year`i' = round(runiform()*4)
    tostring year`i', replace
    replace year`i' = "Super Low" if year`i'=="0"
    replace year`i' = "Kinda Low" if year`i'=="1"
    replace year`i' = "Average to Mediocre" if year`i'=="2"
    replace year`i' = "Pretty High" if year`i'=="3"
    replace year`i' = "Incredibly High" if year`i'=="4"
}
```

I ultimately would like to create a table in LaTeX that presents the frequencies, percentages, and differences in percentages of these two variables. Importantly, I would like to sort it by the frequencies in year 1.

Something along these lines:
[image]

Finding it harder to do than I expected, I came up with the following code (thanks https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1124796-any-way-to-save-row-percentages-output-as-a-matrix):

```
label define order  1 "Pretty High"  2 "Average to Mediocre"  3 "Kinda Low"  4 "Incredibly High"  5 "Super Low"

foreach i in 1 2 {
    encode year`i', gen(y`i'_freq) label(order)
    tab y`i'_freq, matcell(y`i'_freq)
    mata: st_matrix("y`i'_pct", (st_matrix("y`i'_freq")  :/ colsum(st_matrix("y`i'_freq"))))
}

matrix combined = y1_freq, y1_pct
foreach i in 2 {
    matrix combined = combined, y`i'_freq, y`i'_pct
}

mata: st_matrix("c", (st_matrix("combined"), st_matrix("combined")[.,2] - st_matrix("combined")[.,4]))

matrix rownames c = "Pretty High" "Average to Mediocre" "Kinda Low" "Incredibly High" "Super Low"
matrix colnames c = "No. 1 Freq" "No. 1 Pct" "No. 2 Freq" "No. 2 Pct" "Difference"
esttab matrix(c), nomtitles
```

The problem with the above is that I hard-coded the sorting of the variables. How can I generalize this so that it's done automatically?

Any other tips to improve my code are also appreciated.

Comment: `matrix combined = y1_freq, y1_pct, y2_freq, y2_pct` would save you three lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a simpler solution involving `contract` and `merge` of two years. After your initial code run this:

```
foreach i in 1 2 {
    preserve
    contract year`i', f(freq`i') p(pct`i')
    tempfile year`i'
    save `year`i''
    restore
}

use `year1', clear
ren year1 year2
merge m:m year2 using `year2', nogen
ren year2 type
gsort -freq1
replace pct1 = pct1/100
replace pct2 = pct2/100
gen diff = pct1 - pct2
list, clean
```

This will give you a result:

```
                      type   freq1   pct1   freq2   pct2        diff  
  1.             Kinda Low      39   0.26      27   0.18         .08  
  2.           Pretty High      37   0.25      33   0.22    .0266667  
  3.   Average to Mediocre      29   0.19      44   0.29         -.1  
  4.       Incredibly High      24   0.16      23   0.15    .0066667  
  5.             Super Low      21   0.14      23   0.15   -.0133333
```

---

Remarks:

`contract` clears the current dataset and creates a dataset with frequencies  and percentages `year'i'`. The datasets are saved into temporary files to keep the filesystem clean and not to worry about deleting files.

Then the first dataset is merged with the second. Only frequencies and percentages from the second dataset are kept.

The sorting in descending order is done via the `gsort -freq1` command. To sort in ascending order, run `gsort freq1`.

Comment: Thanks—that is a lot simpler than what I had!

Comment: At this point, what is the easiest way to export the current data set to LaTeX?

Comment: Glad it worked!
There is a package `-dataout-` that should do the job. Run these to export the dataset to LaTeX:
`ssc install dataout` and `dataout, save(myfile) tex replace`

Comment: Good answer, but the complete code from creating the data would make it even better.

Answer (score 3):

This is a variation on the previously posted answer by @Andrey Ampilogov.

```
* sandbox code from OP 
clear all
set obs 150
set seed 1234
foreach i in 1 2 {
    gen year`i' = round(runiform()*4)
}

preserve 

stack year1 year2, into(year) clear 
contract year _stack, f(freq) p(percent) 
reshape wide freq percent, i(year) j(_stack) 

* define labels once when needed 
label define year 0 "Super Low"      ///
    1 "Kinda Low"  2 "Average to Mediocre"   ///
    3 "Pretty High"  4 "Incredibly High" 
label val year year 

gsort -freq1
list 

     +-----------------------------------------------------------+
     |                year   freq1   percent1   freq2   percent2 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |           Kinda Low      39      13.00      27       9.00 |
  2. |         Pretty High      37      12.33      33      11.00 |
  3. | Average to Mediocre      29       9.67      44      14.67 |
  4. |     Incredibly High      24       8.00      23       7.67 |
  5. |           Super Low      21       7.00      23       7.67 |
     +-----------------------------------------------------------+

  restore
```

The points of technique I would emphasise are

1. Converting integer values to string doesn't seem a better idea when you can keep the integers and attach value labels when convenient. You would have to look at your original definitions to recover the order information.
2. `merge m:m` is supported by Stata but overkill even when it works. Elaborate file choreography is not needed.
3. For me percents are bounded by 0 and 100 in problems like this. But scaling to proportions and calculating differences is easy enough with the right data structure.

Comment: Thank you for more clarification, Nick. That's a nice way to learn about the `-stack-` command